# How to export/save Evolution contacts as separate .vcf files?

Tags: evolution, contacts

Is there any command or short-cut for saving evolution contacts as separate .vcf files rather than a list.vcf in Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution).

### Step1:

Install latest version of syncevolution from repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository deb http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable main
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syncevolution-evolution
```

syncevolution has a `--print-items` command which shows each contact name & id for a perticular database (evolution contact list; default is `Personal`)

### Step2:

To view all databases(evolution-conatct-list local or online) run this command in terminal:

```
syncevolution --print-databases
```

Copy the database name.

### Step3:

Now Run following command at teminal-prompt with the `database` name:

```
syncevolution --print-items backend=evolution-contacts database=Personal
```

You can replace `Personal` with any other contact-list in evolution.

The output would be something like this:

```
pas-id-5006660000000D81: Tony Stark
pas-id-5017A30900000670: Hockeye
pas-id-51717EFD00000096: Hulk
pas-id-5194ABA900000000: Syncevolution
```

### Step4:

Now export each contact as separate vcf file (pas-id would be names of the files).For Tony stark it would be:

```
syncevolution --export Tony-Stark.vcf backend=evolution-contacts database=Personal --luids pas-id-5006660000000D81
```

To export all contacts at the same time run without `luids` parameter:

```
syncevolution --export ~/Desktop/allcontacts/ backend=evolution-contacts database=Personal
```

It will export all contacts in ~/Desktop/allcontacts directory.

---

I have craete a simple script which exoprt all contacts as file with their names(**as firstnames-lastname.vcf**).

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir ~/Desktop/allcontacts/
cd ~/Desktop/allcontacts/

syncevolution --print-items backend=evolution-contacts database=Personal >database
cat database | while read line
do
 passid=`echo $line | awk -F: '{print $1}'`
 name=`echo $line | awk -F\  '{print $2"-"$NF}'`
 syncevolution --export allcontacts/"$name".vcf backend=evolution-contacts database=Personal --luids "$passid"
done
```

Save the script in gedit as vcf-export.
Then run:

```
chmod a+x vcf-export
./vcf-export
```