# Where is the contacts folder?

Tags: gnome, contacts

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed on my notebook and I want to make a backup of "Contacts" but can not find the location of the folder or location where data is located, to specify the exact path. I do not want to backup all my documents that are already supported in UbuntuOne, only "Contacts".

Comment: are you talking about gnome-contacts or evolution or ubuntuone-contacts?

Comment: Ubuntu gnome-contacts

Comment: Gnome Contacts uses Evolution-data-server to store contacts in a database (`~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook`). You can make backup of that folder or export address-book to vcf(`from evolution`) file & then take backup of that vcf file  or sync your contacts to online services.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Would you like to add that as an answer?

Comment: Oh, I was outside of the realm of midgard! Now its Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome Contacts uses Evolution-data-server to store contacts in a database (`~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook`).

You can make backup of that folder or export address-book to vcf(from evolution) file & then take backup of that vcf file or sync your contacts to online services.

---

To export all contacts separately as with contacts names as file names (i.e `Tony Stark.vcf`, `Peter Parker.vcf`) see this answer:

**[How to export/save Evolution contacts as seperate .vcf files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265083/how-to-export-save-evolution-contacts-as-seperate-vcf-files)**